# Fastest way to compare the properties of two objects

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Someone suggested using reflection for this. The method I have works great, but over 800,000 iterations, I came to the obvious conclusion (that most already came to) that reflection just doesn't cut it.

Here's part of my Helper class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string[] ignoredProperties =
    { 
        "EntityState", 
        "EntityKey", 
        "Prop1", 
        "Prop2", 
        "Whatever", 
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if properties of two objects are the same. Bypasses specified properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="first"></param>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    /// <param name="ignoreProperties"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool PropertiesEquals<T>(this T first, T other, string[] ignoreProperties)
    {
        var propertyInfos = first.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            //Faster with custom method ? Nah...
            //if (FindElementIndex(ignoreProperties, propertyInfo.Name) < 0)

            //Probably faster if hardcoded.... Nah, not really either...
            //if (propertyInfo.Name != "EntityKey" && propertyInfo.Name != "EntityState" && propertyInfo.Name != "Group_ID" && propertyInfo.Name != "Import_status")

            if (Array.IndexOf(ignoreProperties, propertyInfo.Name) < 0)
                if (!Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(first, null), propertyInfo.GetValue(other, null)))
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int FindElementIndex(string[] input, string value)
    {
        int arraySize = input.Length - 1;
        Type valueType = value.GetType();

        for (int x = 0; x <= arraySize; x++)
        {
            if (input[x] == value)
                return x;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

The problem is that those objects, depending on the type, can have up to 50 properties to check. So I can't really do a bunch of `if`s there.

Is there any way I could speed this up a bit?

Thanks.

Comment: Workaround: Use the Equals method and override it for each of your classes to implement the property comparison there (no reflection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I could speed this up a bit ?

Absolutely. If you're going to fetch the same properties multiple times for different objects, create a delegate for each property (see [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) I wrote a while ago for some examples) or use a project like [Hyperdescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces).

(As of .NET 3.5, another way to create the delegate would be to use expression trees and compile them.)

Comment: Your blog post looks very interesting. I'll sure sure read that up. But will I need to create those delegates 'by hand' or I'll be able to create them dynamically depending on the object types I have to compare ?

Comment: @Francis: You can create them dynamically, reasonably easily.

Comment: @JonSkeet the article link seems to be broken, is there another way to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) for creating comparing method dynamically, and then just simply running it. The code will be JITted and run fairly quickly.

There is one downside - you have to know how IL works.

Comment: I think this is somewhat up the same alley http://stackoverflow.com/a/9607001/731678

Answer (score 0):

You can build an **[Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)** where you specify which properties should be compared. You can then compile it as a lambda expression and use it to compare the items with the performance of a delegate call.