# How to compare Two Object -Exclude specific Properties in Comparison

Tags: c#, .net

I have a case there I want to compare two objects in c#.Also I would have option to exclude specific properties when comparing. Can anyone suggest a better approach. Class will look like as below

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressID { get; set; }
    public int AddressStagingID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool PreferredAddress { get; set; }
    public int? DBID { get; set; }
    public Enum AddressStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have a function like

```
private bool IsAddressModified(Address currentAddress,Address existingAddress)
    {
    }
```

Comment: When you say two objects, did you mean two instances of type `Address`?

Comment: @Kosala W ..Yes.question updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606963/fastest-way-to-compare-2-objects-excluding-a-few-properties/9607001#9607001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to develop a different solution using Expression Trees which is, in my opinion, more flexible

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Address a1 = new Address();
       a1.AddressID = "100";
    
       Address a2 = new Address();
       a2.AddressID = "200";
       Console.WriteLine(IsAddressModified(a1,a2,a=>a.AddressID));
    }

   public static bool IsAddressModified(Address a1,Address a2,params Expression<Func<Address,Object>>[] props)
   {
       if(props == null)
          return a1.Equals(a2);
        
      foreach(Expression<Func<Address,object>> memberExpression in props)
      {
          MemberExpression property = memberExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
          if(property != null)
          {
              foreach(PropertyInfo pi in typeof(Address).GetProperties())
              {
                // exclude all properties we passed in
                  if(!pi.Name.Equals(property.Member.Name))
                  {
                    
                      var valueA1 = pi.GetValue(a1);
                      var valueA2 = pi.GetValue(a2);
                      if(valueA1 != null && valueA2 != null)
                          if(!valueA1.Equals(valueA2))
                              return true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    
      return false;
  }
}
```

So what does the code?

1. You can pass an array of 'properties' to the method `IsAddressModified`. These properties will be excluded while comparing.
2. From the Expression I extract a MemberExpression to get the Name of each Property.
3. I iterate through all Properties the type `Address` has and check if it is one property to exclude.
4. Last but not least, I compare the property values.

#### Why so 'complicated' ?

With this solution you can pass as much properties into the function as you like AND you are totally type-safe during compilation.

In the Main you can see how I call this function. Even due to the fact that `AddressID` of `a1` and `a2` differ, the function returns false, because you excluded the `AddressID`.

A full compilable example can be found [here](http://ideone.com/ndLfGR)

Comment: Excellent answer. Can the `public static bool IsAddressModified(Address a1,Address a2,params Expression<Func<Address,Object>>[] props)` be refactored to make this Generic for `T`, like `public static bool IsModified(T a1,T a2,params Expression<Func<T,Object>>[] props)`? Would that work??

Comment: Sure, just take my link with the running example and change it.[see here](http://ideone.com/mxXhzy)

Comment: Note: the above example is only partly generic, using System.Object is not type safe... updated example here: https://ideone.com/KUXCAL

Answer (score 5):

[Compare NET Objects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/) have everything you need!

*Ignore By Expression*

```
CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.IgnoreProperty<Person>(x => x.Name);
```

*Ignore By the ClassName.MemberName*

```
CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.MembersToIgnore.Add("Person.Name");
```

*Ignore All Members with a Name*

```
CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.MembersToIgnore.Add("UpdateDate");
```

*Ignore with a Wildcard*

```
CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.MembersToIgnore.Add("*Id");
```

*Ignore with an Attribute*

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class CompareIgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class Shipment
{
    public long IdentCode { get; set; }
    public String Customer { get; set; }
    
    [CompareIgnore]
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
}

CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.AttributesToIgnore.Add(typeof(CompareIgnoreAttribute));
```

*Compare Only Properties with an Attribute*

```
public class Movie 
{
    [Compare]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal PaymentForTomCruise { get; set; }
}

CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
compare.Config.RequiredAttributesToCompare.Add(typeof(CompareAttribute));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about Reflection:

```
  private bool IsAddressModified(Address currentAddress, Address existingAddress)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in currentAddress.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //To exclude properties use condition
                if (pi.Name != "City") { 
                object currentElement = typeof(Address).GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(currentAddress,null);
                object existingElement = typeof(Address).GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(existingAddress,null);
                if (!currentElement.Equals(existingElement))
                { return false; }
                }
                return true;    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something very simple, use reflection. But if you need something advanced, use [CompareObjects](https://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/). Here is the [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects). This library can give detailed reports on changes as well. Which means you can use it for logging etc.

This is a sample code from the site.

```
//This is the comparison class
CompareLogic compareLogic = new CompareLogic();

//Create a couple objects to compare
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
person1.Name = "Greg";

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.Name = "John";
person2.DateCreated = person1.DateCreated;

ComparisonResult result = compareLogic.Compare(person1, person2);

//These will be different, write out the differences
if (!result.AreEqual)
   Console.WriteLine(result.DifferencesString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force?

```
private bool IsAddressModified(Address a, Address b)
{
    return a.Address1 != b.Address1 || a.Address2 != b.Address2 
       || a.City != b.City || a.PostCode != b.PostCode;
    // etc. for all the properties that are considered as modified
}
```